# create a multidimensional array field in Django model

Tags: python, arrays, django, django-models

I get multidimensional arrays must-have array expressions with matching dimensions error from Django when I try to insert data into my model, below is my model and the data format i have

```
effect = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.IntegerField(
                blank=True,
                null=True
            ),
            null=True,
        ),
        null=True,
        default=list,
        size=11
    )
```

and this is my data format:

```
"effect": [null,[95],[20],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
```

this is how my data looks and my current model field structure isnt working, i will like a solution to problem please.

Comment: Could it be this error only occurs when adding data through the Django Admin? The widget seems incapable of displaying/entering multi-dimensional data. If you store in a shell session (or anywhere programmatically) it will work :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with the ArrayField, but with the Django Admin. The default admin widget expects the Array to be 1-dimensional (both when displaying as when updating).

If you want to use the django-admin you can use something like https://django-jsonform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/arrayfield.html. This ModelField inherits from the original Django ArrayField, but overrides the widget that is used in forms (both Admin Form as regular Form). This field can handle multi-dimensional fields.